Why on resize of swiper container either swiper container becomes blank black or 2 images merges in swiper
My swiper is not working properly upon resize either it show

Black blank screen
Merges next and previous images

My swiper version : "swiper": "^11.1.3",
Here is problem

Codesandbox
Here is what my current code looks like


import { Zoom, Navigation ,Virtual } from 'swiper/modules';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/vue';

import 'swiper/css';

import 'swiper/css/zoom';
import 'swiper/css/navigation';
import 'swiper/css/pagination';
export default{
    data(){
        return {
              slides:[],
              allAssetsList:[],
        }
    },
}
.asset-slider-wrapper{
    height: 100%;
}

.swiper-container,
.swiper-wrapper,
.swiper-slide {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide{
  height: calc(100vh - 60px - env(safe-area-inset-top)) !important;
}

:deep(.swiper-slide){
   height: calc(100vh - 60px - env(safe-area-inset-top)) !important;
   background: #000;
}
 <div class="asset-slider-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-container" >
                <swiper 
                :zoom="true"
                ref="swiperModuleRef" 
                @slideChange="handleSlideChange" 
                @beforeSlideChangeStart="$emit('beforeSlideChange')"
                @touchStart="$emit('touchStart')"
                @touchEnd="$emit('touchEnd')"
                @beforeResize="$emit('beforeResize')"
                @zoomChange="handleZoomChange"
                :resizeObserver="true"
                :style="{'--swiper-navigation-color': '#fff','--swiper-pagination-color': '#fff'}" 
                :navigation="true" :virtual="{
                     addSlidesBefore:2 , addSlidesAfter:2
                }">
                    <swiper-slide
                    v-for="(asset,index) in allAssetsList"
                    :key="index"
                    :virtualIndex="index"
                    style="height:100vh;"
                    >
                    <div class="swiper-zoom-container" style="position:relative;" :assetId="asset._id">
                            <img v-if="isImage(asset)"   :src="getThumbnailPath(asset,true)" :assetId="asset._id"/>
                    </swiper-slide>
                </swiper>
             </div>
 </div>



Note: I'm using virtual slider for better experience on mobile as it was crashing with 600 + images so I'm using virtual slider.

What do you see in your browser devtools when it dissapears?

Don't see any errors or warnings in the console .

I was meaning the DOM or CSS.

I debugged not there the left calculation value was very huge like 45809px

Provide a link where the problem is reproduced. Codesandbox link is not working!
